# for loop that batch the data and throw it out in c++

Tags: c++, mysql

```
void write_token_to_data()
    {
        typedef double* DynamicMatrix[l+m];
        // DynamicMatrix Count;
        typedef double* DynamicMatrix2[l+m];
        //DynamicMatrix2 Prob;
        for(int i=0; i<(l+m); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<(l+m); j++)
            {
                if(mysqlinsert2(i,j,combine[i],combine[j]))
                {
                    cout<<"insert OK!!"<<endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout<<"insert failed"<<endl;
                }


            }
        }

    }//end of function
```

---

here is my question 
how can i change this sub function ,that i can keep i ,j combine[i], combine[j]
until the number 100 , and throw these four value into the mysqlinsert function 
and free the array in the for loop index 101 and continue record the value ,long story short,i want break this mysql insert into small part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 - You can contruct a string in the form
(i,j,cobine[i],combine[j]) for each iteration.
 - Inorder to insert a multiple rows in a single query.
[Normal insert query for multiple records 
 INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), ( Value1, Value2 )
]
 - also rewrite mysqlinsert2(i,j,combine[i],combine[j]) into *mysqlinsert2(str)*.and execute the string.

    for(int i=0; i<(l+m); i++){
      for(int j=0; j<(l+m); j++){
        if (till count => 100) {
          // concatinate the string with prev str
          str += (i,j,combine[i],combine[j])+',';
        }
        if (count reaches hundred || count = 0) {
          // execute the string 
          mysqlinsert2(str);
          // initialize str as empty string
          str = 'INSERT INTO Table ( Column1, Column2, column3, column4 ) VALUES';
          count = 0;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: my question is where to declare the count? is outside the for loop? next question , i 'd like to know where to put the count++ is suitable ?